# TFS Create Main and Development branch from existing team project

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Currently we have a team project in TFS 2010 named **MyApp** that was put in years ago. I would like to create **MAIN** and **DEV** branches as described in the ALM Rangers guide. I know it would've been easier if the existing team project was created with the branches initially, but that's in the past. I don't want to lose the version history in the existing project.

Is it possible to create those branches (or at least a **DEV** branch) without affecting the existing project?

**UPDATE** My folder structure looks something like this (bold is folder, italic is file):

- server\DefaultCollection

  - MyApp

    - **Lib**
    - **packages**
    - **Repositories**
    - **MVCClient**
    - *MyApp.sln*

Comment: Can you post a screenie of your existing folder layout? That can give us an idea of where to go from there...

Comment: @MrHinsh I added what my folder structure looks like.

Comment: With that folder structure I would just make "MyApp" a branch and call it Main.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a great solution to this, but here's one option:

Create a MAIN folder.  Copy all your source under this folder.  Convert MAIN to a branch.  Branch DEV from MAIN.

Keep your old source code around (the stuff not under the MAIN folder) for history purposes.

Comment: Just noticed you're using TFS 2010.  You can do a Move instead of a Copy, but when you upgrade to 2012+ the history will disappear (it may still be there in the database, but you can't see it in the UI).  This is because in 2012 they switched to something called slot mode instead of Item mode for version control.

Comment: This is what I end up doing. MS should've created an easier way to do this, especially for all the people coming from other source control applications.

Comment: Make sure to check in the main folder first, then it can be converted to a branch.